# How to model the design of an Ember JS software?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, uml, class-diagram

I am trying to design software which will be written in **Ember JS (JavaScript)**. From research, some people say you can use UML class diagrams, but JavaScript is not a class-based object-oriented language like Java.

Therefore, I am a bit confused with how I should design the Ember JS software. Can anyone recommend a way of designing the software please, or is it okay to use UML class diagrams?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This shows some UML diagrams you may find useful: http://agilemodeling.com/essays/initialRequirementsModeling.htm

Comment: thanks @xmojmr I will give that a read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily break it down to 3 main things(top to bottom), routes, components and models. The templates act as containers for the routes content. And the content is more or less displayed by components which use the models.

So a class could be representing a component. I´m sure there are many other ways which also make sense. Maybe someone wants the controller to be the main focus. It really depends on what makes the most sense for you.